# Within an admin menu point, set number of posts via input field

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, admin

I'm quite new to Wordpress and currently working on a custom plugin.

I know how to create a new admin menu point via plugin, now I'm trying to figure out how to add a functionality, when entering the site the user shall be able to specify the number of shown posts via input field - the amount of posts shall be saved in a way that you receive a shortcode for the amount.

Hope that was clear. Thanks in advance!

I know there are a lot of Wordpress php codesnippets and shortcuts to use, but I'm uncertain which the ones are I need.

Comment: Is user must registered and be logged in or anyone can specify the number of posts?

Comment: Only the admin!